# RawKeyDownEvent not triggered for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have implemented **RawKeyboardListener** in my Flutter app and it works flawlessly on Android and on Chrome when debugging. When Firebase hosted, it is not catching any keypress event.

```
RawKeyboardListener(
      autofocus: true,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
        if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent') {
            //some action
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.0, 0, 10.0),
        child: Text(keyedText,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 40.0)),
      ),
    )
```

I researched and found I can look for **RawKeyEventDataWeb**. Changed the code for **RawKeyEventDataWeb** instead of **RawKeyDownEvent**, but the problem is **RawKeyEventDataWeb** listened to both up and down key events and hence anything typed comes twice.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the "right" way to solve this. But here is a workaround I figured. Any pair of 'Up' and 'Down' key events are triggered within 200 milliseconds. So I used this fact to ignore any event that is within 200 or so milliseconds. Not the best solution, but works.

```
RawKeyboardListener(
      autofocus: true,
      focusNode: focusNode,
      onKey: (RawKeyEvent event) {
        int currentKeyPressTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
        if (event.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent' ||
            event.data is RawKeyEventDataWeb &&
                currentKeyPressTime > lastKeyPressTime + 200) {
          lastKeyPressTime = currentKeyPressTime;
          // some action
        }
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10.0, 0, 10.0),
        child: Text(keyedText,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 40.0)),
      ),
    ),
```

Just remember to initialize **lastKeyPressTime** sometime before.

Answer (score 0):

Using Flutter-Web (without it being Firebase hosted in my case), the key.runtimeType is different in debug mode than in pre-compiled code. This is how it worked for me:

```
onKey: (key) {
    if (key.runtimeType.toString() == 'RawKeyDownEvent' ||  // debug mode
        key.runtimeType.toString() == 'minified:kW')        // compiled mode
        { ... }
```

Comment: I guess you should operate on the typing system not the raw strings which aren't guaranteed. Example: `event.runtimeType == RawKeyDownEvent`